# Google Mock matching an array

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I know this has been asked multiple times but none of the answers work for me.
This is the mocked func I want to test:

```
  MOCK_METHOD2(sendInternal, void(uint8_t data[], uint8_t size));
```

The test goes like this

```
    uint8_t expectedMessageData[3] = { 0x08, 0xda, 0xff };


    EXPECT_CALL(*serverFake, sendInternal(testing::_,3))
            .With(testing::Args<0, 1>(ElementsAre(0x08, 0xda, 0xff)))
            .Times(1);
```

But this results in

> Expected args: are a tuple whose fields (#0, #1) has 2 elements where
>   element #0 is equal to '\b' (8),
>   element #1 is equal to '\xDA' (218)
>              Actual: don't match, whose fields (#0, #1) are (0x7fcfd9500590, '\x11' (3)), which has 3 elements

To me it seems like Gmock would compare the params and not the array's elements.

I've even built a custom matcher:

```
MATCHER_P2(HasBytes, bytes, size, "") {
    uint8_t * dataToCheck = arg;
    bool isMatch = (memcmp(dataToCheck, bytes, size) == 0);
    return isMatch;
}
```

I can see (while debugging) that isMatch == true but the test still fails.

Please help!

Comment: How do you use your matcher? 
It seems that gmock is trying to compare 2 element array, while the call happens with 3 element array (which is weird). Have you tried using `ElementsAreArray()` matcher?, Also, have you tried to force invoking of a function with a different array (e.g. having 4 elements), to see if the error message changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I did not reproduce your problem. The following example compiles and the test passes:

```
class ServerFake {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(sendInternal, void(uint8_t data[], uint8_t size));
};

// If only possible, I recommend you to use std::vector instead of raw array
class ServerFake2 {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(sendInternal, void(std::vector<uint8_t> data));
};

MATCHER_P2(HasBytes, bytes, size, "") {
    // unnecessary assignment, I think ...
    uint8_t * dataToCheck = arg;
    bool isMatch = (memcmp(dataToCheck, bytes, size) == 0);
    return isMatch;
}

using ::testing::ElementsAre;

TEST(xxx, yyy) {

    ServerFake* serverFake = new ServerFake;
    ServerFake2* serverFake2 = new ServerFake2;

    uint8_t expectedMessageData[3] = { 0x08, 0xda, 0xff };
    std::vector<uint8_t> expectedMessageData2({ 0x08, 0xda, 0xff });

    EXPECT_CALL(*serverFake, sendInternal(HasBytes(expectedMessageData, 3), 3)).Times(1);
    // the code below compiles and passes as well! However, I didn't check why;
    // EXPECT_CALL(*serverFake, sendInternal(testing::_,3))
    //     .With(testing::Args<0, 1>(ElementsAre(0x08, 0xda, 0xff)))
    //     .Times(1);
    serverFake->sendInternal(expectedMessageData, 3);


    // much better, do like this!
    EXPECT_CALL(*serverFake2, sendInternal(ElementsAre(0x08, 0xda, 0xff))).Times(1);
    serverFake2->sendInternal(expectedMessageData2);


    delete serverFake;
    delete serverFake2;
}
```

Second, `ElementsAre` officially does not support C-style arrays, according to [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/zbowmXOF4v0). If you really cannot change your method signature, and you really wish to use `ElementsAre` on your raw array, you can use the hack proposed in that topic. Cheers.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, got kinda lost in work :) Moving to std::vector actually solved this issue, thank you!